# Is Equilibrium Solution Always Constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning introductory course of Differential Equation. Textbook has written such a nuance of that equilibrium solution tends to be a constant.

I had asked my instructor the same queation as the title of thIs OP and she answered it always be when it is autonomous, however not when it is forcing function.

I don't know what forcing functions. Any  specific example could I be given for the case that equalibrium solution is not constant?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_function_(differential_equations)

Answer (score 2):

The solution of (linear) differential equations is made of the superposition of a term that solves the non-homogeneous equation and is the response to external sollicitations, and a term that solves the homogeneous equation and conveys the initial conditions.

In physical (stable) systems, the homogeneous terms are decaying and represent transient behavior. After decay, only the true response remains.

In the case of an autonomous system, the non-homogeneous part is zero, and so is the corresponding response, leading to a constant equilibrium.

In other cases, I personally wouldn't speak of an equilibrium, but rather of a *steady-state*. For instance, in the case of a periodic forcing function (sinusoid), the response is also periodic (after the transient part has vanished).

For aperiodic excitation, the meanings of equilibrium or steady-state become fuzzy.

On the plot below, the total response to a sinusoidal excitation is made of a steady-state sinusoid (dotted red) and a transient (dotted blue):

[image]

Comment: $+1$ for *steady state* !